# Find all points on the elliptic curve using irreducible polynomials

Tags: elliptic-curves

Hello I am new to the subject of Cryptography. Following is the question I have to solve.

Topic is Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC)..

> In the elliptic curve E (g2, g7) over the GF(2^4) field: Find the
>   equation of the curve. Find all points on the curve using x4+x3+1 as
>   irreducible polynomial

I am facing problem in finding all the points on the curve. by using E(g2, g7) I created equation

> y^2 + xy = x^3 + g^2 x^2 + g^7

can someone please explain me the steps to find all the points. In Reference Book (figure 10.15 of the Forouzan’s book 2nd edition). Author did not explained how he find out all the points.

Waiting for detailed answer.